# Android AdMob's test ads not loading on Pixel 2

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

I wanted to add ads to my applications, so I started with an empty app that uses the sample app id from AdMob to test the ads. Well, the ads won't load. You can see the whole app's code and the log below. I don't know what did I mess up, I followed the getting started guide, but the only result I got is...
`I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0`
The test ads show up on my other devices (old Samsung and Huawei phones), but not on my main device. Which is a Pixel 2 with Android 11.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
...
      <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
...
</application>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/mainAdBanner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
package com.csakitheone.adtest

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MobileAds.initialize(this)

        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mainAdBanner.loadAd(adRequest)
    }
}
```

LOG

```
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0
W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lw@fa2be90
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1757)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1874)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:792)
        at ci.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203315097@20.33.15 (150400-0):1)
        at ci.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203315097@20.33.15 (150400-0):6)
        at lx.A(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203315097@20.33.15 (150400-0):10)
        at lh.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203315097@20.33.15 (150400-0):3)
        at eb.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203315097@20.33.15 (150400-0):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at ja.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@203315097@20.33.15 (150400-0):6)
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0
```

Comment: Do You have an internet connection in the emulator? I have copy-pasted Your code and everything is working. I only got `failed to load : 0` when I turn on offline mode.

Comment: I can't use an emulator so my app is on my physical device. I have stable WiFi and cellular connection.

Answer (score 0):

It was my phone's fault. I did a factory reset and everything is working fine.